# Function with a Struct stuck in an input loop

Tags: c++, function, struct

I am writing a basic program for class to manage an event list.  I have a void function with a struct to enter new data which is stuck in a loop.  The struct is created and after completing the data entry portion it loops back and repeats.

I have tried enclosing it in a `do{}while loop`, and tried to break it down by a series of `if` statements.  Is there a command or dialogue to exit or terminate the struct?

As requested, the bare minimum:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

void menu();
void AddANewEvent();

struct Event{    //struct to hold event data, name, location, description, date, start time, and duration

     string EventName;
     string EventLoc;    // location for the event
     string EventDesc;   //describe the event
     string Date;        //date in DD/MM/YYYY format
     string StartTime;    //time to start in 24H format
     float Duration;       //time in whole hours
};

int main()
{
menu();
//AddANewEvent();  removed this and it works...
return 0;
}

void menu(){
     int action = 0;
     cout << "Event List Management Menu" << endl;
     cout << "1.  Add new event" << endl;                                  //  add a new event, almost feeling positive about this part but it may be delirium.
     cout << "Please select an action (1): " ;                                     //prompt user for input
     cin >> action;                                                                                //storing input

     switch(action)
     {
          case 1: AddANewEvent(); break;
     }}

void AddANewEvent(){
          Event evn;
                    cout << "Enter event name: " << endl;
                    cin >> evn.EventName;
                    cout << "Enter event location: " << endl;
                    cin >> evn.EventLoc;
                    cout << "Enter event description: " << endl;
                    cin >> evn.EventDesc;
                    cout << "Enter date: " << endl;
                    cin >> evn.Date;
                    cout << "Enter start time: " << endl;
                    cin >> evn.StartTime;
                    cout << "Enter duration in hours: " << endl;
                    cin >> evn.Duration;
} //end of the function
```

This is where my problem is stemming from:

```
void AddANewEvent(string &fileName){
     Event evn;
     cout << "Enter event name: " << endl;
     cin >> evn.EventName;
     cout << "Enter event location: " << endl;
     cin >> evn.EventLoc;
     cout << "Enter event description: " << endl;
     cin >> evn.EventDesc;
     cout << "Enter date: " << endl;
     cin >> evn.Date;
     cout << "Enter start time: " << endl;
     cin >> evn.StartTime;
     cout << "Enter duration in hours: " << endl;
     cin >> evn.Duration;
} //end of the function
```

I think my struct is okay:

```
struct Event{    //struct to hold event data, name, location, description, date, start time, and duration

     string EventName;
     string EventLoc;    // location for the event
     string EventDesc;   //describe the event
     string Date;        //date in DD/MM/YYYY format
     string StartTime;    //time to start in 24H format
     float Duration;       //time in whole hours
};
```

In other portions of this program I have successfully implemented similar segments where the function can be continued or exited with a yes or no question.  However, in this segment it will not work.  Ideally, after this section of code is processed it will then prompt to repeat and otherwise return to the main.  All my attempts thus far have not been able to return, only to repeat the dialogue unintentionally.

Comment: Post a [mcve] reproducing your problem as required here please. Also may I ask what you observed when debugging your code stepping through line by line?

Comment: You seem to be having trouble with a loop, but no where in your question do you include the code where your problem is occurring. I recommend you read [how to make a minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `AddANewEvent ` creates a new `Event` which it never returns, so it only consumes input without producing anything.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  Bare minimum is added.  It doesn't give me any warnings or flags, it just loops. davidlowryduda There is no intentional loop, but it loops anyway...  molbdnilo I removed the portion which writes it to a file prior to posting.

Comment: Well I fixed it by removing the ```AddANewEvent``` function from the ```main```.  I don't understand why it was looping but this has fixed the problem...

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by adding a user-def constructor in the `Event` class, so that you can use `emplace_back` to store your events in a `std::vector`. Keep in mind that if you decide to use the `addNewEvent()` then the `emplace_back` will trigger a copy instead of utilizing the move constructor.

Use a simple `while` loop and break out of it when the user doesn't want to continue adding more events.

Example: https://rextester.com/IAO89219